# Problema con Grub en dual-boot (Dejó de funcionar después de actualización en Windows 10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

Qué tal, buenas a todos. El día de hoy actualicé Windows 10 (al parecer una actualización importante) y después de varios problemas con el booteo de la máquina me he dado cuenta de que no puedo volver a bootear Ubuntu, antes de postear aquí hice TODO lo que pude sin lograr nada, sigue booteando windows sin que aparezca grub para poder elegir otro sistema operativo, estoy desesperado y acudo a esta comunidad con la esperanza de poder recuperar grub.

Les dejo el log del repair-tool:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25776234/

El bcdedit se ve así desde win10:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en la bios que tienes como prioridad de arranque?

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice @LuisFernando checa en la bios prioridad de arranque del sistema operativo, ya que a veces windows se apropia de esta después de una actualización.

Answer (score 0):

Mas de alguna vez me pasó a mi al tener instalado varias distros linux en la misma pc y pude recuperar el grub instalando el cd o dvd live de ubuntu e identificar en que particion esta instalada boot si es que no esta en la misma particion de ubuntu. 
Para que puedas realizarlo sin ningun problema te recomiendo que leas esta guia para recuperar el grub [Guia para recuperar el grub en ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2012/07/recuperar-el-arranque-o-grub2-de-ubuntu.html)